# Prisma not liked posts from followed users

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

I am trying to get all ***posts from followed users such that the posts have not been liked by the following user (aka me).***

how can i create a schema and query such a thing?

I currently have this:

```
model User {
  id        String  @id @default(autoincrement())
  username  String
  followers Follows[] @relation("follower")
  following Follows[] @relation("following")
  likes Post[] @relation(references: [id])
}

model Follows {
  follower    User @relation("follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  String
  following   User @relation("following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId String

  @@id([followerId, followingId])
}

model Post {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  title String
  likedBy User[] @relation(references: [id])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in the schema:

1. The relation in `Follows` table seemed reversed, (i.e. `followerId` should be mapped to the `following` relation on the `User` model
2. I assume each post is made by a user, so I added the `author` field in the `Post` model
3. `autoincrement()` uses `Int` type, so `cuid()` is used instead in `User` model

Updated schema:

```
model User {
  id        String    @id @default(cuid())
  username  String
  followers Follows[] @relation("follower")
  following Follows[] @relation("following")
  posts     Post[]    @relation("author")
  likes     Post[]    @relation(references: [id])
}

model Follows {
  follower    User   @relation("following", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  String
  following   User   @relation("follower", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId String

  @@id([followerId, followingId])
}

model Post {
  id       Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  title    String
  authorId String
  author   User   @relation("author", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  likedBy  User[] @relation(references: [id])
}
```

To get all unliked posts from followed users:

```js
const posts = await prisma.post.findMany({
    where: {
        likedBy: {
            none: {
                id: 'cl3g1s5a20011llvcsllnzlra', // same as followerId
            },
        },
        author: {
            followers: {
                some: {
                    followerId: 'cl3g1s5a20011llvcsllnzlra',
                },
            },
        },
    },
});
```

- `some`: Returns all records where one or more ("some") related records match filtering criteria.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#some

- `none`: Returns all records where zero related records match filtering criteria.

  - You can use `none` without parameters to return all records with no relations

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#none

Comment: i should have mention that i need posts from followed users that **I (the user following someone) have not liked.** Not the posts with 0 likes. apologies

Comment: Answer updated, just filter userId with `none` operator